# Convergence using ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to test the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{1}{(x^n + x^{-n})} $$
for $x>0$.

I just read d'Alembert's ratio test and after practicing a number of exercises, this question which asks for what values of $x$ does the above series converge and diverge, boggled the mind.

For $x=1$, it is clearly divergent. However, I am unable to deduce what happens when $x>1$ or $x<1$?

Answer (score 4):

If $x>1$, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x^{n+1}+x^{-n-1}}}{\frac{1}{x^n + x^{-n}}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+x^{-2n}}{x + x^{-2n-1}} = \frac{1}{x} < 1$$

so by the ratio test the sum converges. Now try the other case $x<1$.

Answer (score 2):

$x>0\implies \begin{cases}x^n+x^{-n}\ge x^n\\x^n+x^{-n}\ge x^{-n}\end{cases}$ use which one is convenient on each interval.